# how to select optional parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g, nvl

I am trying to pass mandatory  and optional parameter in sql query using bind variable.

The Condition like , If I entered(in WHERE CLAUSE) mandatory parameter(with some value) and optional parameter that could be EMPTY(it means it should be blank ) as a bind variable it should  displayed some row's that satisfy the mandatory parameter condition. 
but If I haven't entered Mandatory parameter and only  entered optional parameter it should not display any row's. because mandatory parameter is empty.
How should I achieve this: 
 My query is :

```
select employee_id,hire_date 
from employees
where employee_id between  :from_emp_id   and  :to_emp_id      
  and  hire_date.......?(what?)**
```

what should I do with HIRE_DATE, if hire_date is empty then it will replace by sysdate and return row's.

Answer (score 4):

```
...
and hire_date = nvl( :hire_date, hire_date)
```

This is an expression that evaluates to true if the hire_date matches the :hire_date parameter, or if :hire_date was passed in as a null/empty value

Answer (score 0):

We can use CASE to accomplish this.

```
create table Employee (employee_id int, hire_date datetime null)

insert into Employee (employee_id, hire_date)
select 1, '2011-01-01'
union all
select 2, '2012-03-01'
union all
select 3, '2011-10-01'
union all
select 4, null

declare @hiredate datetime

set @hiredate = '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000'

select * from Employee where isnull(hire_date, GETDATE()) = case 
when (@hiredate is null) then isnull(hire_date, GETDATE()) Else @hiredate End

set @hiredate = null
select * from Employee where isnull(hire_date, GETDATE()) = case 
when (@hiredate is null) then isnull(hire_date, GETDATE()) Else @hiredate End
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hire_date is a NOT NULL field, then you can do the following:

```
and (:hire_date is null or hire_date = :hire_date)
```